# Display user info in widget with Amplify flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, aws-amplify

I have the following code to get the current logged-in user in Flutter with Amplify

libs/common/controller/auth_controller.dart

```
part 'auth_controller.g.dart';

@riverpod
class AuthenticateController extends _$AuthenticateController {
  Future<AuthUser> _fetchUser() async {
    final currentUser = await Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();

    safePrint("Username : ${currentUser.userId}");

    return currentUser;
  }


  @override
  FutureOr<AuthUser> build() async {
    return _fetchUser();
  }
}
```

How do I display the user information in my widget? I have tried:

libs/features/pet/ui/pet_list_page.dart

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final currentUser = ref.watch(authenticateControllerProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          currentUser.value!.userId,
```

Is this the correct way to fetch user details with riverpod? I would like to display the user's name in the appbar on every page

Comment: You can select specific fields from your state object and this will only refresh when the selected field change ex. `final userId = ref.watch(authenticateControllerProvider.select((value) => value.userId));`